# How to modify an event through a Runnable

Tags: java, runnable, bukkit

I have a runnable that fires on an event. I am trying to get a list from the event and clear it, but put the list in Metadata storage in the entity that is created during the event. So far I have tried:

Note: the class this is in implements and is an event listener.

```
@EventHandler
public synchronized void playerDeathEvent(final EntityDeathEvent event) {

    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Entity p = event.getEntity();
            // Spawn the Firework, get the FireworkMeta.
            Firework fw = (Firework) p.getWorld().spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.FIREWORK);
            FireworkMeta fwm = fw.getFireworkMeta();

            // Our random generator
            Random r = new Random();   

            // Get the type
            int rt = r.nextInt(4) + 1;
            Type type = Type.BALL;       
            if (rt == 1) type = Type.BALL;
            if (rt == 2) type = Type.BALL_LARGE;
            if (rt == 3) type = Type.BURST;
            if (rt == 4) type = Type.CREEPER;
            if (rt == 5) type = Type.STAR;

            //Get our random colors   
            int r1i = r.nextInt(15) + 1;
            int r2i = r.nextInt(15) + 1;
            Color c1 = getColor(r1i);
            Color c2 = getColor(r2i);

            // Create our effect with this
            FireworkEffect effect = FireworkEffect.builder().flicker(r.nextBoolean()).withColor(c1).withFade(c2).with(type).trail(r.nextBoolean()).build();

            // Then apply the effect to the meta
            fwm.addEffect(effect);

            // Generate some random power and set it
            int rp = r.nextInt(2) + 1;
            fwm.setPower(rp);

            // Then apply this to our rocket
            fw.setFireworkMeta(fwm);  
            // Clear drops and set the drops to be released on explosion

            //TODO: fix problem where list is cleared before put into Metadata
            List<ItemStack> list = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
            for (ItemStack stack : event.getDrops())
                list.add(stack);
            fw.setMetadata("dropItems", new FixedMetadataValue(GLDPlugin, list));
            event.getDrops().clear();
            forceDelete(event);
        }
    });

}

public void forceDelete(EntityDeathEvent event) {
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getDrops().size(); i++)
        event.getDrops().remove(i);
}
```

And (just the last section):

```
            @EventHandler
            public synchronized void onEntityDeath(EntityDeathEvent evt)
            final EntityDeathEvent event = evt;

            //No code in this section was changed from the code above.

            //TODO: fix problem where list is cleared before put into Metadata
            List<ItemStack> list = new ArrayList<ItemStack>();
            for (ItemStack stack : event.getDrops())
                list.add(stack);
            fw.setMetadata("dropItems", new FixedMetadataValue(GLDPlugin, list));

        }
    });
    evt = event;
    evt.getDrops().clear();
    forceDelete(evt);
}
```

In the top one, it will NOT clear `event.getDrops()` and WILL put `list` into the entity's metadata, duplicating `event.getDrops()`. In the bottom example, it WILL clear `event.getDrops()` but will NOT put `list` into the entity's metadata, obliterating `event.getDrops()`. Both of these outputs are unacceptable, as this causes no items or double items to be spawned. Any ideas?

Edit: Better explanation for those of you who are more bukkit-savvy:

I am trying to make it so the player does not drop items on death, but they are still removed from their inventory. I also need it so the `List<ItemStack>` is put into the spawned firework's metadata.

Comment: `event.getDrops()` may be passing you a copy of the `List`

Comment: @MadProgrammer that is what it is doing when `EntityDeathEvent` is final, but when it isn't I can clear it. I understand that final makes it constant, but I need to get a way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling:

```
Firework.setMetadata(String, MetadataValue);
```

Which is essentially the [`Metadatable.setMetadata()`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/metadata/Metadatable.java#L12-L20) method. Here is the documentation for this method:

```
/**
 * Sets a metadata value in the implementing object's metadata store.
 *
 * @param metadataKey A unique key to identify this metadata.
 * @param newMetadataValue The metadata value to apply.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If value is null, or the owning plugin
 *     is null
 */
public void setMetadata(String metadataKey, MetadataValue newMetadataValue);
```

Therefore, there is **no guarantee** that after setting `"dropItems"` Metadata of an item, anything would happen at all. You must implement a listener that checks when fireworks are destroyed, then drop the items if the firework includes this metadata. **MetadataValue is not NBT Value.**

To modify NBT value, you will have to directly retrieve from CraftBukkit through reflection, like this:

```
Firework fw = (Firework) p.getWorld().spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.FIREWORK);
java.lang.reflect.Field _entity_ = CraftEntity.class.getField("entity");
_entity_.setAccessible(true);
net.minecraft.server.Entity entity = _entity_.get(fw);
// et cetera
```

In short: Don't. Write a custom event handler to check for the Metadata values when fireworks explode, and act on that correspondingly.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I did not think that simply putting Metadata titled `dropItems` would make it spawn the items. I do have a listener (using protocollib, as firework explosions aren't implemented) and it works very well when used with my test command, which essentially does the same thing but instead does not have to clear a list. My problem is that I can either clear the list and not spawn anything, or not clear the list and fail to make this plugin. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @itrollin98 I don't think I understand what you're trying to convey here.

Comment: I am trying to make it so the entity does not drop items on death but the firework has a Metadata value containing the list of drops.